# Adapt AutoCAD VBA to work in Excel

Tags: excel, autocad, vba

I have written a code (with help) that works in AutoCAD VBA but I'd like to adapt it so I can run it from Excel and integrate it into a longer macro. I've tried replacing `ThisDrawing` with `ACAD.ActiveDocument` but this isn't working. Here's my full AutoCAD VBA code:

```
Public Sub Section()
    Dim SolidObject As Acad3DSolid
    Dim NewRegionObject As AcadRegion
    Dim PlaneOrigin As Variant
    Dim PlaneXaxisPoint As Variant
    Dim PlaneYaxisPoint As Variant
    Dim PickedPoint As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    With ThisDrawing.Utility
        .GetEntity SolidObject, PickedPoint, vbCr & "Select solid to cut."
        If Err Then
            MsgBox "Selected solid must be a 3DSolid"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        PlaneOrigin = .GetPoint(PickedPoint, vbCr & "Select point to define origin.")
        PlaneXaxisPoint = .GetPoint(PickedPoint, vbCr & "Select point to define x-axis.")
        PlaneYaxisPoint = .GetPoint(PickedPoint, vbCr & "Select point to define y-axis.")
        Dim minPoint As Variant, maxPoint As Variant
        Set NewRegionObject = SolidObject.SectionSolid(PlaneOrigin, PlaneXaxisPoint, PlaneYaxisPoint)
        With NewRegionObject
            MsgBox "Area: " & .Area
            MsgBox "Perimeter: " & .Perimeter

            .GetBoundingBox minPoint, maxPoint
            MsgBox "Min Point coordinates: (" & minPoint(0) & "," & minPoint(1) & "," & minPoint(2) & ")"
            MsgBox "Max Point coordinates: (" & maxPoint(0) & "," & maxPoint(1) & "," & maxPoint(2) & ")"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You should check the MSDN documentation if the objects you call are available in excel. For example SolidObject and NewRegionObject

Comment: First off, did you load AutoCad library into your VBA project?

Comment: Yeah, I loaded it in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use this function to see if there's a running instance of AutoCad and, if there is, get it:

```
Function Set_Acad(Acad As AcadApplication) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Acad = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application") 'Get a running instance of the class AutoCAD.Application
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set_Acad = Not Acad Is Nothing
End Function
```

to be exploited in your main code as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Section()
    Dim SolidObject As Acad3DSolid
    Dim NewRegionObject As AcadRegion
    Dim PlaneOrigin As Variant
    Dim PlaneXaxisPoint As Variant
    Dim PlaneYaxisPoint As Variant
    Dim PickedPoint As Variant

    Dim Acad As AcadApplication '<--| declare a variable of type 'AcadApplication'

    If Not Set_Acad(Acad) Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if there's no Autocad running instance, otehrwise set 'Acad' variable to it

    With Acad.ActiveDocument.Utility '<--| now you can use Acad to reference 'Autocad' application and all its objects/methods/properties

        On Error Resume Next
       .GetEntity SolidObject, PickedPoint, vbCr & "Select solid to cut."
        If Err Then
            MsgBox "Selected solid must be a 3DSolid"
            Set Acad = Nothing
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        PlaneOrigin = .GetPoint(PickedPoint, vbCr & "Select point to define origin.")
        PlaneXaxisPoint = .GetPoint(PickedPoint, vbCr & "Select point to define x-axis.")
        PlaneYaxisPoint = .GetPoint(PickedPoint, vbCr & "Select point to define y-axis.")
        Dim minPoint As Variant, maxPoint As Variant
        Set NewRegionObject = SolidObject.SectionSolid(PlaneOrigin, PlaneXaxisPoint, PlaneYaxisPoint)
        With NewRegionObject
            MsgBox "Area: " & .area
            MsgBox "Perimeter: " & .Perimeter

            .GetBoundingBox minPoint, maxPoint
            MsgBox "Min Point coordinates: (" & minPoint(0) & "," & minPoint(1) & "," & minPoint(2) & ")"
            MsgBox "Max Point coordinates: (" & maxPoint(0) & "," & maxPoint(1) & "," & maxPoint(2) & ")"
        End With
    End With

    Set Acad = Nothing    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a line in AutoCAD (must be opened) from Excel
But you have to go in Tools->References and add [**AutoCAD 20xx Type Library**]

```
    Sub testline()
    Dim app
    Dim lineObj As AcadLine
    Dim startPoint(0 To 2) As Double
    Dim endPoint(0 To 2) As Double

    On Error Resume Next
        Set app = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If (app Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub

    startPoint(0) = 100
    startPoint(1) = 100
    startPoint(2) = 0
    endPoint(0) = 200
    endPoint(1) = 200
    endPoint(2) = 0

    Set lineObj = app.Documents(0).ModelSpace.AddLine(startPoint, endPoint)

End Sub
```